# Axios interceptor refresh token for multiple requests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios

I'll throw the http request because I'm calling the refresh token when it returns 401. After the refresh token response, I need to throw the previous request

SAMPLE
Logın ->  — 1 hours later—  —> call product —> 401 —> call refresh token —> call product

I try this link [a link](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/axios-interceptors-re-call-last-action/45247) and look this link [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53523003/axios-interceptors-last-request) but doesn't work.

Catch the 401 error

```
setInterceptors = () => {
        axios.interceptors.response.use(
            response => {
                return response;
            },
            err => {
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    if (err.response.status === 401 && err.config && !err.config.__isRetryRequest) {

                        const originalRequest = err.config;

                        this.emit('onAutoLogin', originalRequest);
                    }
                    // throw err;
                });
            }
        );
    };
```

Call my action

```
jwtService.on('onAutoLogin', originalRequest => {
                    jwtService
                        .signInWithToken()
                        .then(res => {
                            if (res.access_token) {
                                originalRequest.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + res.access_token;


Axios.request(originalRequest).then(response => {
                                    store.dispatch({
                                        type: ** MY PROBLEM İS HERE **
                                        payload: response.data
                                    });
                                });
                            }
                        })
                        .catch(err => {
                            jwtService.setSession(null); 
});
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the problem is other than "it doesn't work"? Is there an error? Is it just not dispatching the action? Is the action dispatched but not handled? What have you tried to do in debugging?

Comment: Is your originalRequest really the entire err.config object? Or did you mean to destructure it?

Comment: Refresh token is in worked. originalRequest really the entire err.config object. I also called the last http operation with originalRequest. But I can't hold the action (type, payload) required to trigger the returned data.

Comment: Yes, I see a comment on the line where the `type` would be. And what is the problem? It is unclear what "can't hold the action..." means.

Comment: I can't get the last action in Redux.

Comment: It isn't clear from your snippets if `store` is in scope or if it's even defined, and we've no idea what your action/reducer pair looks like, and you still haven't presented *what* is not working. Is there an error? Stack trace? Certainly there has to be more information available to help debug. Is it possible to create a shareable codesandbox that reproduces your issue so other can see what you see?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

using [this link](https://gist.github.com/Godofbrowser/bf118322301af3fc334437c683887c5f) I was able to solve the problem without triggering the redux store.

```
let isRefreshing = false;
 let failedQueue = [];

       const processQueue = (error, token = null) => {
            failedQueue.forEach(prom => {
                if (error) {
                    prom.reject(error);
                } else {
                    prom.resolve(token);
                }
            });

            failedQueue = [];
        };

axios.interceptors.response.use(
            response => {
                return response;
            },
err => {
                const originalRequest = err.config;

                if (err.response.status === 401 && !originalRequest._retry) {
                    if (isRefreshing) {
                        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                            failedQueue.push({ resolve, reject });
                        })
                            .then(token => {
                                originalRequest.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token;
                                return axios(originalRequest);
                            })
                            .catch(err => {
                                return Promise.reject(err);
                            });
                    }

                    originalRequest._retry = true;
                    isRefreshing = true;

                    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                        axios
                            .post('/fooUrl/refreshToken', {
                                refreshToken: "fooToken"})
                            .then(({ data }) => {
                                axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + data.fooToken;
                                originalRequest.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + data.fooToken;
                                processQueue(null, data.fooToken);
                                resolve(axios(originalRequest));
                            })
                            .catch(err => {
                                processQueue(err, null);
                                store.dispatch(showMessage({ message: 'Expired Token' }));

                                reject(err);
                            })
                            .then(() => {
                                isRefreshing = false;
                            });
                    });
                }

                return Promise.reject(err);
            }
        );
```