# Refresh JWT Token using Axios request interceptor (interceptors.request) - Multiple requests at once problem

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuex

I'm using this code to intercept every HTTP call in Axios, in order to keep the user logged in by refreshing the JWT token when it expires:

```
const { token } = window.localStorage;

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_API_ENDPOINT,
    withCredentials: false,
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: token && token.length > 0 ? `Bearer ${token}` : ""
    }
  });

axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(request => {
    if (request.url.endsWith("refresh")) {  // prevent infinite loop
      return request;
    }

const { expiryDate } = window.localStorage;
const currentTimestamp = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000);

if (expiryDate && currentTimestamp >= expiryDate) {
  console.log("token expired.");

  return store
    .dispatch("auth/refreshToken")  // refreshToken action will place the token in localStorage.token
    .then(() => {
      const newToken = window.localStorage.token; 

      request.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${newToken}`;

      return Promise.resolve(request);
    })
    .catch(() => Promise.resolve(request));
}
console.log("token not expired.");

return request;

});
```

This used to work fine until I added more requests at page load, each request is trying to refresh the token which causes an error in the back-end. How do I solve this problem? I have searched a lot but all the solutions I found were for `interceptors.response` [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57890667/axios-interceptor-refresh-token-for-multiple-requests), I'd like to use `interceptors.request` because logging in is optional and there will be no 401 response if the user is not logged in.

EDIT: Based on the answer from User 28 below the code has changed to:

```
axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(async config => {
    if (config.url.endsWith("refresh")) {
      // if we are making a refresh token call, return it to prevent infinite loop
      return config;
    }

    await axiosInstance.refreshingToken;

    const { expiryDate } = window.localStorage; // token expiry date

    const currentTimestamp = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000);

    if (expiryDate && currentTimestamp >= expiryDate) {
      axiosInstance.refreshingToken = store.dispatch("auth/refreshToken"); // this will update the token in localstorage
      await axiosInstance.refreshingToken;
    }

    const { token } = window.localStorage; // grab the token from localstorage

    config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;

    return config;
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a global variable to determine you have to wait or not. The easiest way is to assign it to the axios instance.

Example Code:

```js
axios.interceptors.request.use(async config => {
  if (isRefreshTokenRequest) {
    return config
  }

  if (axios.refreshingToken) {
    await axios.refreshingToken
  }

  if (isTokenExpired) {
    axios.refreshingToken = store.dispatch('auth/refreshToken')
    await axios.refreshingToken
  }

  // set authorization header

  return config
})
```

Comment: I updated the code to use this approach, however, it's still sending more than 1 refresh token request, I have a Vue component that fires 3 requests in `mounted()` and all three are sending refresh token request to the API which causes an issue because the API removes the refresh token from the database after a refresh is done. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @GreenTrain Ah, It's my bad. See [this](https://jsfiddle.net/kL8emrs0/15/). Open the DevTools and see the log and network request.

Comment: What I changed is adding a new if condition at `await axios.refreshingToken`. At first I think it should be fine even if `refreshingToken` is undefined. But it makes code asynchronous so the second request cannot get value of `refreshingToken` which set from the first request. After adding if condition the first request will go through to set `refreshingToken` synchronously.