# Stop multiple request sent on refresh token using axios-auth-refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am using `axios-auth-refresh` axios interceptor 3rd party [**library**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-auth-refresh) to handle my refresh token, the issue is that i have multiple request on my dashboard *around 10 request* and every time when the token expires, it will execute the my refresh token function multiple times and based on how many requests that are made.  I previously refer to this stackoverflow [**question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57890667/axios-interceptor-refresh-token-for-multiple-requests)  but it didn't somehow work on me and some requests are not being made then I opt at using `axios-auth-refresh` library to handle my refresh token function, because I thought that the option `pauseInstanceWhileRefreshing: true` will help me prevent it but it didn't somehow work.

What I want to achieve is to execute a single refresh token request to the server while other requests are on queue *(I am using cookie to store my token)*, once it successfully replace the token then it will **retry or resend** those request back to the server.  Below is my code:

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import axiosRetry from 'axios-retry';
import config from 'config';
import {isNull, isUndefined} from 'underscore';
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';
import createAuthRefreshInterceptor  from 'axios-auth-refresh';

const api_client = () => {
    const client = axios.create({baseURL: config.server});
    const cookies = new Cookies();

    client.interceptors.request.use(request => {
        const cookies = new Cookies();
        const cookieToken = cookies.get('token');
        const cookieUser = cookies.get('user');
        if(!isNull(cookieToken) && !isNull(cookieUser)) {
            if(!isUndefined(cookieToken.token)) {
                request.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${cookieToken.token}`;
            }

            request.withCredentials = true;
            request.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
            request.headers['X-Fname'] = cookieUser.username;
        }

        return request;
    }, error => {
        console.log(error);
    });

    const handleRefreshAuth = failedRequest => {
        return getRefreshAuthToken().then(response => {
            if(response.data) {
                cookies.remove("token", { domain: window.location.hostname, path: "/grt" });
                cookies.remove("token", { domain: window.location.hostname, path: "/" });
                cookies.set("token", { token: response.data.token, refreshToken: response.data.refreshToken, }, { domain: window.location.hostname, path: "/grt", expires: new Date(Date.now() + 259200) });
                failedRequest.response.config.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${response.data.token}`;
                return Promise.resolve();
            }
        })
    }

    const options = {
        pauseInstanceWhileRefreshing: true
    }

    createAuthRefreshInterceptor(client, handleRefreshAuth, options);

    const getRefreshAuthToken = () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const cookieToken = cookies.get('token');
            const cookieUser = cookies.get('user');
            if((!isNull(cookieToken) && !isNull(cookieUser)) || (!isUndefined(cookieToken) && !isUndefined(cookieUser))) {
                client.post(`/user/refresh?refreshToken=${cookieToken.refreshToken}`).then(response => {
                    if(response) {
                        resolve(response)
                    }
                })
            }
        })
        
    }

    return client;
}

export const retrieve = async (url, data = undefined) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        await api_client().get(url, data).then(response => {
            if(response) {
                resolve(response.data);
            }
        })
    })
}

export const send = async (url, data = undefined) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        await api_client().post(url, data, { skipAuthRefresh: true }).then(response => {
            if(response) {
                resolve(response.data);
            }
        })
    })
}

export default {retrieve, send};
```

**Network**
[image]

**Old code**
I added this one as well, it might be that I missed something else on this one, using raw `axios` interceptor method, same issue as the new one.

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import axiosRetry from 'axios-retry';
import config from 'config';
import {isNull, isUndefined} from 'underscore';
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';

const api_client = () => {
    const client = axios.create({baseURL: config.server});
    let isRefreshing = false;
    let failedQueue = [];
    const retryCodes = [
        401
    ]
    axiosRetry(client, {
        retries: 3,
        retryDelay: (retryCount) => {
            return retryCount * 1000;
        },
        retryCondition: (error) => {
            return retryCodes.includes(error.response.status);
        }
    });

    client.interceptors.request.use(request => {
        const cookies = new Cookies();
        const cookieToken = cookies.get('token');
        const cookieUser = cookies.get('user');
        if(!isNull(cookieToken) && !isNull(cookieUser)) {
            if(!isUndefined(cookieToken.token)) {
                request.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${cookieToken.token}`;
            }

            request.withCredentials = true;
            request.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
            request.headers['X-Fname'] = cookieUser.username;
        }

        return request;
    }, error => {
        console.log(error);
    });

    const processQueue = (error, token = null) => {
        const cookies = new Cookies();
        console.log('processQueue', token)
        failedQueue.forEach(prom => {
            if (error) {
                prom.reject(error);
            } else {
                const cookieToken = cookies.get('token');
                prom.resolve(cookieToken.token);
            }
        })
        
        failedQueue = [];
    }

    const getRefreshAuthToken = async () => {
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            const cookies = new Cookies();
            const cookieToken = cookies.get('token');
            const cookieUser = cookies.get('user');
            if((!isNull(cookieToken) && !isNull(cookieUser)) || (!isUndefined(cookieToken) && !isUndefined(cookieUser))) {
                await client.post(`/user/refresh?refreshToken=${cookieToken.refreshToken}`).then(response => {
                    if(response) {
                        resolve(response)
                    }
                })
            }
        })
        
    }

    client.interceptors.response.use(response => {
        return response;   
    }, error => {
        const originalRequest = error.config;
        const cookies = new Cookies();
        if (error.response.status === 401 && !originalRequest._retry) {
            if (isRefreshing) {
                return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                    failedQueue.push({ resolve, reject });
                }).then(response => {
                    if(response) {
                        console.log('from test response', response)
                        cookies.remove("token", { domain: window.location.hostname, path: "/grt" });
                        cookies.remove("token", { domain: window.location.hostname, path: "/" });
                        cookies.set("token", { token: response.data.token, refreshToken: response.data.refreshToken, }, { domain: window.location.hostname, path: "/grt", expires: new Date(Date.now() + 259200) });
                        originalRequest.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${cookies.get('token').token}`;
                        return client(originalRequest);
                    }
                }).catch(error => {
                    return Promise.reject(error);
                });
            }

            originalRequest._retry = true;
            isRefreshing = true;
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                getRefreshAuthToken()
                .then(response => {
                    if(!isUndefined(response)) {
                        cookies.remove("token", { domain: window.location.hostname, path: "/grt" });
                        cookies.remove("token", { domain: window.location.hostname, path: "/" });
                        cookies.set("token", { token: response.data.token, refreshToken: response.data.refreshToken, }, { domain: window.location.hostname, path: "/grt", expires: new Date(Date.now() + 259200) });
                    }
                    processQueue(null, cookies.get('token').token);
                    resolve(client(originalRequest));
                }).catch(error => {
                    // add to queue for failed requests
                    processQueue(error, null);
                    reject(error);
                }).then(() => {
                    isRefreshing = false
                });
            });
        }
        return Promise.reject(error);
    })

    return client;
}

export const retrieve = async (url, data = undefined) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        await api_client().get(url, data).then(response => {
            if(response) {
                resolve(response.data);
            }
        })
    })
}

export const send = async (url, data = undefined) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        await api_client().post(url, data, { skipAuthRefresh: true }).then(response => {
            if(response) {
                resolve(response.data);
            }
        })
    })
}

export default {retrieve, send};
```

Does anyone knows how to fix this? If so, please let me know, thanks!

Comment: Could any of the comments on this issue at GitHub be helpful? https://github.com/Flyrell/axios-auth-refresh/issues/156

Comment: Hi @Tor Raswill, I tried the comments on the GitHub but didn't help me.  Any other solutions?