# Automatically refreshing access token by AXIOS interceptor request

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

My React App uses Axios for API-requests.

Axios adds access token into headers every API-request by request interceptor. I want check expiry date before current request will be sent. If access token expired, axios should make refresh action, change access token in store and then make first request from app with new token.

For refreshing and other API-actions I use Redux Toolkit Slices.

I have no any cases when refreshing in request interceptor works fine. I found solutions with response interceptor, but it's not my way.

How can I refresh access token in request interceptor?

This is my axios instance:

```
export const createAPI = (): AxiosInstance => {
  const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: getAPIURL(),
    timeout: REQUEST_TIMEOUT,
    withCredentials: true
  });

  api.interceptors.request.use(
    async (config: InternalAxiosRequestConfig) => {
      const accessToken = store.getState().user.accessToken;

      if (accessToken && config.headers) {
        config.headers['authorization'] = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;
      }
      
      // todo Check access token and refresh if it expired

      if (!config.data) return config;
      
      config.data = adaptFromClientToServer(config.data);

      return config;
    }
  );

  api.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => {
      if (!response.data) return response;
      
      response.data = adaptFromServerToClient(response.data);
      
      return response;
    }
  );

  return api;
};
```

Comment: So basically doing this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57890667/axios-interceptor-refresh-token-for-multiple-requests but in the interceptor request.

Comment: @ValRob It would have been better to form your question as an entirely new post with a better [mcve] and more complete details than this post has provided and not been received well. Any answer to ***your*** question won't answer the OP's question here, since you've since stipulated ***different*** requirements. However, doesn't it make sense to check the token first when making requests than to let the client make invalid requests and create unnecessary network traffic, exactly what OP is asking here?

Answer (score 3):

Your createApi module looks on the right tracks, to wrap common API logic (which gets more complex over time) and simplify code in views and view models. My answer is about design choices for portable and resilient API clients.

**TOKEN RESPONSES**

A token response always contains an `expires_in` field. Note also that the access token may be an opaque / unreadable token rather than a JWT:

```json
{
   "token_type":"bearer",
   "access_token":"_0XBPWQQ_c0f0677f-5aa9-4c4e-a3d4-c0f53db4037a",
   "refresh_token":"_1XBPWQQ_197003c2-704f-4475-923c-2b40e5f5d696",
   "scope":"openid profile",
   "expires_in":900
}
```

**REFRESH CHOICES**

The frontend can hold onto the `expires_in` field and the time of issuance, and manage refresh via one of these methods:

1. Do a refresh before API requests if the current time indicates the token is close to expiry
2. Do a refresh on a background timer when the token is close to expiry
3. Do a refresh if an API returns a 401 status

**RESILIENCY**

Access tokens can fail for reasons other than expiry. One cause can be revocation. In some setups it can be caused by infrastructure events such as token signing key renewal or a load balancing failover. Therefore always do option 3 (the primary behaviour), and combine it with option 1 or 2 (optimizations) depending on your preference.

**CONCURRENCY**

Token refresh should be synchronized if multiple views call APIs at the same time. This leads to a design of queueing up promises, but only making the refresh request on the first, then resuming all API requests with the new access token. Code like this could be used:

```js
public async synchronizedRefresh(): Promise<void> {
    await this._concurrencyHandler.execute(this._performTokenRefresh);
}
```

**FURTHER INFO**

For more about these concepts, see these resources of mine. My code does not use Axios interceptors, but [token refresh code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.tokenhandler.docker/blob/master/src/agent/authorizationServerClient.ts#L83) would be easy to integrate into your ones.

- [API client blog post](https://authguidance.com/api-journey-client-side/)
- [Example Axios Code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.desktopsample.final/blob/master/src/api/client/fetchClient.ts#L91)

Answer (score 2):

When checking whether a token has expired in the request interceptor, it's important to note that if the token is not expired on the frontend, it doesn't necessarily mean it's still valid on the backend. There may be a time lag between the frontend and backend systems. To ensure token validity, it's advisable to implement solutions on both the request interceptor and response interceptor.

Moreover, in scenarios where the API URL is public, there's no need to initiate a token refresh if a token isn't required. In such cases, it's efficient to skip the refresh token API call. This approach helps optimize token management by avoiding unnecessary refresh operations when tokens are not in use.

Relying solely on the request interceptor to check the refresh token is not a recommended approach.

Answer (score 1):

this is simply how you handle it

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(
  async (config) => {
    const token = store.getState().user.accessToken;
    if (token) {
      config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
      // decode the token and check if (token.exp < Date.now() / 1000)
      if (isTokenExpired(token)) {
          // Call your refresh token endpoint
          // you have to implement an endpoint to get the refresh token
          // if you use 3rd party auth servers, you make requests to their /refreh enpoints
          const newToken = await refreshToken();
          if (newToken) {
            // Token refreshed, update the Authorization header with the new token
            config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${newToken}`;
            // Retry the original request
          }    
        } 
      }
    }
    return config;
  },
  (error) => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`jose`](https://github.com/panva/jose) (or similar) library to extract the [`exp`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.4) claim from the token. It is a numeric date, and you easily compare it with the current time (minus a few seconds to account for potential latency). Use a `Promise` to handle multiple requests

```
let refreshingPromise = null;

api.interceptors.request.use(async (config) => {
    if (refreshingPromise) {
        await refreshingPromise;
    }

    let accessToken = store.getState().user.accessToken;
    const claims = jose.decodeJwt(accessToken);
    const expiration = new Date(claims.exp * 1000);
    const now = new Date();
    now.setSeconds(now.getSeconds() - 10);

    if (now > expiration) {
        if (!refreshingPromise) {
            refreshingPromise = // your refresh logic
        }
        await refreshingPromise;
        accessToken = store.getState().user.accessToken; // Update the access token
        refreshingPromise = null;
    }

    if (accessToken && config.headers) {
        config.headers['authorization'] = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;
    }

    if (config.data) {
        config.data = adaptFromClientToServer(config.data);
    }

    return config;
});
```

Comment: Thanks! - but the problem is when there are multiple requests. There is a solution tho for handling it in the response. But I would love to know the solution for the multiple requests.

Comment: Added a way to handle multiple requests. Might not work out of the box, but you get the idea.